# Session commit does not work for error:ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

My application that uses Spring JDBC, has a "Select For Update...wait 1" sql which issues a lock on the table row. I do a commit after that so that the lock gets removed. This is working in the jetty (Jetty data source is org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource) but not in tomcat (org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource).

I commit as shown below: getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection().commit()

Any help, appreciated !!